# During dataTable ajax request a hidden form control never gets initialized

Tags: jquery, datatables, forms

I have a DataTable `var table = $('#example').dataTable()` which is supposed to be populated when a value in a dropdown changes. I want to select an entry in a dropdown, and that action shall trigger an AJAX request passing the `val()` of the selected entry as an ID for the query.

I also have a `select` control on the form, which is empty at design time, and is populated by another AJAX query. Last but not least I have a hidden control which stores the ID before it is actually posted by the DataTable:

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" id="objs" style="display:none">
  </select>
</div>

<input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="oid" name="oid" value="0">
```

Here is how I do the rest:

```
$('#objs').change(function() {
  $('input[name="oid"]').val(this.value);
  table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
      data: {oid: $('#oid').val()}
    }
  });
  //alert($('input[name="oid"]').val());
  table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

The dropdown `onchange` event handler works perfectly and displays objects's IDs in an alert box. However the Chrome debugging tools show that that `oid` form control **never gets initialized**. So the form which is internally created by the DataTable is posted without the object ID. Here is how it looks like:

```
Array
(
  [oid] => 
)
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect there might be some variable scope issues or the DataTable merely disregards current value of `oid` when it fires `ajax.reload()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the value for `data:` will be given when the `$('#objs').change(function()` is initialized, not when it's called.

Change the `data`declaration to a function and then it will work:

```
table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
      data: function ( d ) {
        d.oid = $('#oid').val();
      }
    }
});
```